# Android and json using gson from REST service with nested objects

Tags: java, android, json, rest, gson

I'm encountering problem with my android app for REST service.

I got following json response from server:

```
{
"0": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Some Guy",
    "email": "example1@example.com"
},
"1": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Person Face",
    "email": "example2@example.com"
},
"3": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Scotty",
    "email": "example3@example.com",
    "fact": {
        "hobbies": ["fartings", "bikes"]
    }
}
}
```

My objects are:

User class:

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("id")
private
int id;

@SerializedName("name")
private
String name;

@SerializedName("email")
private
String email;

@SerializedName("fact")
private
Fact fact;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Fact getFact() {
    return fact;
}

public void setFact(Fact fact) {
    this.fact = fact;
}

public User(){}
}
```

Fact class:

```
public class Fact {
@SerializedName("hobbies")
private List<Hobbies> hobbies;

public List<Hobbies> getHobbies() {
    return hobbies;
}

public void setHobbies(List<Hobbies> hobbies) {
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
}

public Fact(){}
}
```

Hobbies class:

```
public class Hobbies {
private String hobby;

public String getHobby() {
    return hobby;
}

public void setHobby(String hobby) {
    this.hobby = hobby;
}

public Hobbies(){}
}
```

When I use below code in my app:

```
private User jsonToUser(String result){
  User users = null;
  if(result != null && result.length() > 0){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    users = gson.fromJson(result, User.class);
  }
return users;
}
```

Object returned by function is filled by nulls. I've tried to use class Users which is empty and extends ArrayList

```
public class Users extends ArrayList<User> {
//
}
```

and app was giving me error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

I wish to use it for:

```
ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, users);
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong, please? It worked for my twitter timeline app, but doesn't wor for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `users = gson.fromJson(result, User.class);` would work, if you want to convert a JSON string like `{ "id": 1, "name": "Some Guy", "email": "example1@example.com" }` into **one** `User` object.

But a JSON string like yours

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Some Guy",
        "email": "example1@example.com"
    },
    ...
}
```

is interpreted as an Array *(or HashMap?!)* of `User` objects.

Try the following using Array:

```
users = gson.fromJson(result, User[].class);
```

or (if GSON interprets it as a `HashMap`):

```
users = gson.fromJson(result, HashMap<String, User>.class);
```

**The more elegant way** using code from [Collections example](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples) from the Gson user guide would be using Collection:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<User>>(){}.getType();
Collection<User> users= gson.fromJson(result, collectionType);
```

In the "Collections limitations" part is written the following:

> While deserializing, Collection must be of a specific generic type

I'm not sure, but that could mean, that you have to to set `collectionType` to use `List` and not `Collection` as specific type.

**or** (if GSON interprets it as a `HashMap`):

```
Type hashMapType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, User>>(){}.getType();
HashMap<String, User> users= gson.fromJson(result, hashMapType);
```

Good luck =)

**EDIT**

My try with the last solution was successul:

```
public class User {
    private String id, name, email;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = ""
            + "{\"0\": {    \"id\": 1,    \"name\": \"Some Guy\",    \"email\": \"example1@example.com\"},"
            + "\"1\": {    \"id\": 2,    \"name\": \"Person Face\",    \"email\": \"example2@example.com\"}"
            + "}";

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type hashMapType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, User>>() {
    }.getType();
    HashMap<String, User> users = gson.fromJson(result, hashMapType);
    for (String key : users.keySet()) {
        printUser(users.get(key));
    }
}

private static void printUser(User user) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", user.getId(), user.getName(),
            user.getEmail());
}
```

Comment: I've tried all 4 of possible resolutions and I keep getting error: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2` . At line                 Type `collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<User>>(){}.getType();
users = gson.fromJson(result, collectionType);`
I've tried to google for that error, but all resolutions don't apply to my (json) response from server

Comment: Did you try to replace new `TypeToken<Collection<User>>` with `new TypeToken<List<User>>`?

Comment: I injected modified json and it's working: https://gist.github.com/Averus89/86df9ff67840713c0f17

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Json I received from server wasn't valid. ;)

Comment: I tried out my intends and it was **successful with my last solution!** `Type hashMapType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, User>>(){}.getType();`